# Bookmark controller with IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, cache, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm just doing a small hobby project to solve a little problem I have and I'm using it as a learning exercise for ASP.Net MVC 5, .Net Core 2 and Bootstrap.

I'm using a nuget package that handles interaction with a 3rd party api (EveStandard), I make the api calls that I need, spin up a view model which holds the data I want to present to my view.

I'm posting to ask 2 things.

1. Have I applied MVC correctly here?
2. The IMemoryCache (for now) only has a lookup, populated by the controller for id's to their human-readable name. I want this to be an application-wide cache and I don't understand why I have to inject it into the controller. All I want to do is apply a transform in the view layer to a data item on my model. As far as I understand it I would have to do this transformation in the controller and supply an extra piece of data added to the model everytime. I just want a static helper method that I would have somewhere to do the lookup in an adhoc manner as the project grows.

### Model:

```
public class BookmarkViewModel
{
    public BookmarkViewModel(BookmarkSection personalBookmarks, BookmarkSection corpBookmarks)
    {
        PersonalBookmarks = personalBookmarks;
        CorpBookmarks = corpBookmarks;
    }

    public Dictionary<int, UniverseIdsToNames> UniverseMapping { get; set; }

    public BookmarkSection PersonalBookmarks { get; set; }
    public BookmarkSection CorpBookmarks { get; set; }
}

public class BookmarkSection
{
    public BookmarkSection(List<BookmarkFolder> folders, List<Bookmark> bookmarks)
    {
        BookmarkFolders = folders;
        Bookmarks = bookmarks;
    }

    public List<BookmarkFolder> BookmarkFolders { get; set; }

    public List<Bookmark> Bookmarks { get; set; }
}
```

### View Index.cshtml:

```
@using EVEStandard.Models
@model BookmarkViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Bookmark";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <h1>Bookmarks are available once you have logged in.</h1>
}
else
{
    <nav>
        <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Personal</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">Corp</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_BookmarkView", Model.PersonalBookmarks)
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
            @await Html.PartialAsync("_BookmarkView", Model.CorpBookmarks)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

#### BookmarkView (partial)

```
@model BookmarkSection
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@

@functions {

    /// <summary>
    ///     Converts an universe ID into the human readable version by checking the application
    ///     memory cache
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Universe ID</param>
    /// <returns>Unknown or the real name</returns>
    private string GetHumanReadable(int id)
    {
        var name = "Unknown";
    //var cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    //if (Model.UniverseMapping.ContainsKey(id))
    //{
    //    name = Model.UniverseMapping[id].Name;
    //}

        return name;
    }

}

@if (Model.Bookmarks.Any() == false)
{
    <h2>You don't have any bookmarks in this section.</h2>
}
else
{
    var accordionId = $"accordion{Model.Bookmarks.First().BookmarkId}";
    var accordionDataParent = $"#{accordionId}";

    <div class="accordion" id="@accordionId">

        @foreach (var folder in Model.BookmarkFolders)
        {
            <div class="card">

                @{
                    var headingId = "heading" + folder.FolderId;
                    var collapseId = "collapse" + folder.FolderId;
                    var collapseDataTarget = "#collapse" + folder.FolderId;
                }
                <div class="card-header" id=@headingId>
                    <h2 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="@collapseDataTarget" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="@collapseId">
                            @folder.Name
                        </button>
                    </h2>
                </div>

                <div id="@collapseId" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby=@headingId data-parent="@accordionDataParent">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <table class="table .table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                <th scope="col">System</th>
                                <th scope="col">Created</th>
                                <th scope="col">Owner</th>
                                <th scope="col">Notes</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach (var bookmark in Model.Bookmarks.Where(x => x.FolderId == folder.FolderId))
                            {
                                <tr>

                                    <td> @bookmark.Label </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @{
                                            var locationName = GetHumanReadable((int) bookmark.LocationId);
                                        }
                                        @*Todo: Make this open the system on dotlan.*@
                                        @locationName
                                    </td>
                                    <td> @bookmark.Created </td>
                                    <td>
                                        @{
                                            var charName = GetHumanReadable((int) bookmark.CreatorId);
                                        }

                                        @charName
                                    </td>
                                    <td> @bookmark.Notes </td>

                                </tr>
                            }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

### Controller:

```
public class BookmarkController : Controller
{
    private readonly EVEStandardAPI _api;
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public BookmarkController(EVEStandardAPI api, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _api = api;
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        AuthDTO auth;
        try
        {
            auth = User.EsiAuth();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            return Content("You must auth with eve online.");
        }

        //Grab bookmarks
        var personalBookmarkSection = await GetPersonalBookmarkSection();
        List<int> universeIds = GetIdsForCaching(personalBookmarkSection);

        var corporationBookmarkSection = await GetCorporationBookmarkSection();
        universeIds.AddRange(GetIdsForCaching(corporationBookmarkSection));

        //Query ESI for real name
        var universeMapping = await ConvertIdToName(_memoryCache, universeIds);

        var viewModel = new BookmarkViewModel(
            personalBookmarkSection,
            corporationBookmarkSection);// {UniverseMapping = universeMapping};

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    private static List<int> GetIdsForCaching(BookmarkSection section)
    {
        //Grab the id's we want to find out the real name for
        var universeIds = section.Bookmarks.DistinctBy(x => x.CreatorId).Select(x => x.CreatorId).ToList();
        universeIds.AddRange(section.Bookmarks.DistinctBy(x => x.LocationId).Select(x => x.LocationId));
        return universeIds;
    }

    private async Task<BookmarkSection> GetPersonalBookmarkSection()
    {
        var bookmarks = await _api.Bookmarks.ListBookmarksV2Async(User.EsiAuth());
        var folders = await _api.Bookmarks.ListBookmarkFoldersV2Async(User.EsiAuth());

        var section = new BookmarkSection(folders.Model, bookmarks.Model);
        return section;
    }

    private async Task<BookmarkSection> GetCorporationBookmarkSection()
    {
        var auth = User.EsiAuth();
        var charInfo = await _api.Character.GetCharacterPublicInfoV4Async(auth.CharacterId);

        var bookmarks = await _api.Bookmarks.ListCorporationBookmarksV1Async(auth, charInfo.Model.CorporationId);
        var folders = await _api.Bookmarks.ListCorporationBookmarkFoldersV1Async(auth, charInfo.Model.CorporationId);

        var section = new BookmarkSection(folders.Model, bookmarks.Model);
        return section;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Pair Id's and their real name
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="memoryCache"></param>
    /// <param name="universeIds"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<Dictionary<int, UniverseIdsToNames>> ConvertIdToName(IMemoryCache memoryCache, List<int> universeIds)
    {
        if (!memoryCache.TryGetValue(MemoryCacheKeys.UniverseMapping, out Dictionary<int, UniverseIdsToNames> universeMapping))
        {
            universeMapping = new Dictionary<int, UniverseIdsToNames>();
            memoryCache.Set(MemoryCacheKeys.UniverseMapping, universeMapping, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
            {
                Priority = CacheItemPriority.NeverRemove
            });
        }

        foreach (var id in universeIds)
        {
            if (universeMapping.ContainsKey(id) == false)
            {
                universeMapping.Add(id, null);
            }
        }

        var idsToQuery = new List<int>();
        if (universeMapping.Any(x => x.Value == null))
        {
            foreach (var kvp in universeMapping)
            {
                if (kvp.Value == null)
                {
                    idsToQuery.Add(kvp.Key);
                }
            }
        }

        if (idsToQuery.Count > 0)
        {
            var affiliation = await _api.Universe.GetNamesAndCategoriesFromIdsV3Async(idsToQuery);
            foreach (var mapping in affiliation.Model)
            {
                universeMapping[mapping.Id] = mapping;
            }
        }

        return universeMapping;
    }
}
```